# Sending an EMail to GMX using .NET 4.7 and C#

Tags: .net, email, gmx

I am trying to send an E-Mail to GMX in .NET 4.7 old MVC application. I have tried many things but I still receive this error:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
> authenticated. The server response was: Authentication required

My code is:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress(contact.Email);
mail.To.Add("myEmail@gmx.de");
mail.Subject = "Subject";
mail.Body = "Body";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.gmx.net", 587);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myEmail@gmx.de", "password");

client. Send(mail);
```

I have checked the email and the password and they seem to be correct. I am running it locally on "https://localhost:44360/" with SSL activated from Visual Studio. I have also tried to set the DeliveryMethod to Network and it did not help.

Any idea?